# HTML to PDF in NodeJS with Puppeteer always Blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, puppeteer

I have a NodeJS API which has an end-point who is responsible for receive some HTML from Quill Text Editor and then generate a .PDF file with this HTML content, but my downloaded .PDF file is always blank.

Here is my API end-point:

```
server.post('/exportarDocumento', checkDocumento, (req, res) => {
const documento = req.body.documento;

try {
    gerarPDF(documento)
        .then(pdf => {

            console.log('PDF GERADO', pdf); // the output is a Buffer

            res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Length': pdf.length });
            res.send(pdf);
        });

} catch (e) {
    console.log('erro: ', e);
}
finally {
   // do stuff
}});
```

**gerarPDF()** function:

```
async function gerarPDF(documento) {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setContent(documento, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });

await browser.close();

return pdfBuffer; };
```

And my axios call in ReactJS to the endpoint:

```
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/exportarDocumento', { documento: this.props.text })
        .then(response => {
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = 'Documento.pdf';
            link.click();
        });
```

The .PDF file is being downloaded, but is always blank. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If `gerarPDF` throws an error, it will not be caught by `catch (e) { console.log('erro: ', e); }`. You should use `gerarPDF(...).then(...).catch(...)` instead.

Comment: Ok, will fix it. But the pdf still blank, do you have any Idea?

Comment: This is not an answer for your question, but you might try Gotenberg — this is Docker-powered API for converting to PDF. And I wrote small JS/TS client for it — https://github.com/yumauri/gotenberg-js-client